# Keep getting Invalid author specified. Example: A U Thor <author@example.com>

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Using Eclipse Indigo and egit, everytime I commit a pop up appears
and has my name and email in the author and committer boxes.  They look fine.  however, egit tells me:

> ```
> Invalid author specified. Example: A U Thor <author@example.com>
> ```

when, I copy and paste `A U Thor <author@example.com>` into the author box, the message goes away. I can even edit it back to my name and email and it is fine.  which makes no sense - what was wrong with it in the first place?

Similar problem happens with committer box.  I get:

> ```
> Invalid committer specified. Example: C O Mitter <committer@example.com>
> ```

Answer (score 15):

Commit from command line: `git commit -m "message"`

The next commit from eGit will work.

Comment: Elegant. Maybe it needs some default configuration, which is set by pushing once.

Answer (score 6):

When looking at the [org.eclipse.jgit.util.RawParseUtils_ParsePersonIdentTest](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/util/RawParseUtils_ParsePersonIdentTest.java#L56-L82) and the [org.eclipse.jgit.util.RawParseUtils#parsePersonIdent()](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/util/RawParseUtils.java#L694-L746) function, I can only imagine some special character or some Git configuration (user.name, user.email) missing.

Those settings should be enteredd in a configuration entry:

[image: new Entry]

The function which calls the parsing is [`org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.dialogs.CommitMessageComponent#checkCommitInfo()`](https://github.com/eclipse/egit/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.ui/src/org/eclipse/egit/ui/internal/dialogs/CommitMessageComponent.java#L427-L463)

If you user name and email are correctly set, then it can be an [Egit or JGit bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=egit).
A bit like "[bug 377969: EGit rebase does not valide user.name and user.email config properly](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=377969)" (on Linux).

Comment: This worked for me, had close close eclipse and reopen it - at least I believe that was the case as even after doing that it wasnt working for a moment - I did try the "link with editor and selection" option in Git Staging which may have helped, it then showed no repo selected so went and selected the repo again, back to git staging and now it does show my email addy in the Author and Committer fields.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the message you are getting:

`Invalid author specified. Example: A U Thor <author@example.com>`

It simply means that it wants info in indicated format.

For example, if your name is James Bond then you need to type

`James Bond <bond@unknown.com>`

You can do the same in both rows.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54449161/5381704

Fill both the entries:

`Author`

`Committer`

Answer (score 0):

Are you committing to git directly or to a gerrit review system? At least gerrit has case sensitive mail addresses, so they have to be entered exactly as known by the server.

In our company environment that has led to some confusion as they are stored as Jon.Doe@example.com in the LDAP server, but most people tried jon.doe@example.com with egit and got exactly your error messages.

Another trivial alternative would be some kind of bogus whitespace at the beginning or end of your author name in the configuration. You might not see it in the error messages. I have seen this kind of error happening when people copied content from a webpage into a rich text editor which stored more than the "pure" text.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fill out below of form.

### Name and e-mail is your account name and e-mail.

Author :  davidLEE   
Committer : davidLEE

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean the Project
2. Commit again, will appear Author and Committer automatically as below image.[image]