# Invalid author specified message in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit, spring-tool-suite

I started getting the following when trying to commit in Eclipse (STS) when clicking the `Commit` button:

[image]

Tried to follow what people are saying [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176914/keep-getting-invalid-author-specified-example-a-u-thor-authorexample-com) without luck.

Eclipse seems to be properly configured:

[image]

Git works fine from the command line, but this issues really prevents me from using Git integration in Eclipse.

It used to work fine all along, this just started happening today.

I tried update the plugins in Eclipse, didn't help.

I'm on a Mac: 
[image]

and using STS 3.9.5
[image]

What am I missing?

Any suggestions besides totally reinstalling Eclipse(STS)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out it was complaining about the `Author` & `Committer` boxes in the `Commit Message` window:

[image]

As soon as I filled out those boxes, the issue disappeared.